# Authenticate with to https via LabVIEW

Tags: labview

How to authenticate to https web service using LabVIEW?
I am able to authenticate to http web service via HTTP Client, but I cannot authenticate to https through HTTP Client.

Comment: Do you mean REST API communication? Did you try JKI REST Client API library (https://www.vipm.io/package/jki_lib_rest_client/)?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to create an automated tool to upload files to cloud. What I am trying to do is to authenticate to the web server, login (username, password), then upload the file.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have tried and the errors you are receiving.

Comment: If you are using the basic HTTP VIs shipped with LV: The OpenHandle.vi has a boolean input "Verify Server". Have you tried setting this to False? This bool is about checking the certificate, and only applies to https connections.

Answer (score 0):

@Sally, When you say cloud, do you mean GDrive, OneDrive kind of products? If yes, then you need to use OAuth with REST APIs. You may need to create a client and a security token. Using that token you can then establish a secure connection and file Upload and Download. I have recently come across a similar requirement where I had to use GDrive and Google Docs. Luckily I found a toolkit

https://github.com/ni/labview-gdrive